# Selenium with TestRail Integration with latest version

Tags: selenium, testrail

I am using gurock API to get the test case Status from Test Rail

The below will return the status of TC.. I will provide trRunID in the pom.xml. and TCname will be taken using method Name.

```
    public static int FetchTestRailResult(String trRunId, String TCName, String trusername, String trpassword )
                throws MalformedURLException, IOException, APIException {

            int val=0;
            APIClient client = new APIClient($testRailurl);

            client.setUser(trusername);
            client.setPassword(trpassword); 
;
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) client.sendGet("get_tests/"+trRunId+"&status_id=1");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = (JSONObject) (array.get(i));
                String testrailTestCaseName=c.get("title").toString().split("_")[1];
                if (testrailTestCaseName.equals(TCName)) {
                    val=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return val;

        }
```

The below will update the results.

```
public static void UpdateResultToTestRail(String trusername, String trpassword, String trRunId,String testCaseName,String status, String testStepDetails)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException, APIException {

    APIClient client = new APIClient($testrailurl);
    
    client.setUser(trusername);
    client.setPassword(trpassword); 

    HashMap data = new HashMap();
    data.put("status_id", status);
    data.put("comment", testStepDetails);

    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) client.sendGet("get_tests/"+trRunId);
    //System.out.println(array.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = (JSONObject) (array.get(i));
        String testrailTestCaseName=c.get("title").toString().split("_")[1];
        if (testrailTestCaseName.equals(testCaseName)) {
            System.out.println(c.get("id"));
            client.sendPost("add_result/" + c.get("id"), data);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I am now migrating to maven and Now it has dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codepine.api/testrail-api-java-client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codepine.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>testrail-api-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It does not have the api methods and it has Builder and build but further could not able to check connection is successful or not.. Anyone used testrail in Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used that library, but it looks fairly easy to use it and they have some docs on their githib project page: https://github.com/codepine/testrail-api-java-client

For your use case, I think you just need to do the following:

```java
TestRail testRail = TestRail.builder("https://some.testrail.net/", "username", "password");
Tests tests = testRail.tests();
List<Test> lst = tests.list(runId).execute();
//filter it based on your conditions
```

I did not run the code - just composed it, so it might have some issues, but should give you an idea on how to use the library.
Please note, that as of Feb 26, [TestRail is changing](https://blog.gurock.com/announcing-testrail-6-7/) their HTTP response for bulk requests (like cases, tests, projects, etc), so I'm not sure if that library will still work with the next TR version - you will need to check it.

P.S. We are developing some set of products for integration with TestRail, so you might want to look at them. If you are interested, please check out our products:
https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin
https://www.agiletestware.com/firefly

Comment: Struck up on SSL handshake error.. Debugging that

Comment: Maybe your TR server has self-signed cert?

Comment: Worked out.. Added selfsigned certificate.. and your code perfectly worked with slight change. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your testing framework (JUnit of TestNG), try to use one of these libs:

- [TestRail-JUnit](https://github.com/RSheremeta/TestRail-JUnit)
- [TestRail-TestNG](https://github.com/RSheremeta/TestRail-TestNG)

Both of them have Medium articles on how to integrate it just in a few steps (see README.md there)

Comment: Upvoting.  This also looks fine solution.. but unfortunately we did not have case id not added in the test case. We are getting test id by matching test case name.

Comment: You can get the test case Id by navigating to the corresponding test case and check the url, which should be smth like this - https://your-testrail-link.testrail.io/index.php?/cases/view/3 - so 3 is an Id, which could be matched in autotests

Comment: since we have 300+ test case.. which needs to take case id.. may be if there is no other choice we have to go this...

Comment: @ChanGan setting an Id - is 1-time activity, which doesn't need to be rewritten or smth else, so once you made it - you don't need to get back to it (only in case of new tests automated), so I highly recommend these Libraries and most efficient, fast and simple way.

Comment: The two articles you have given, we need to download jar which is not possible for us since we are creating maven dependency

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your point. What's the problem of downloading jar and add it as a Maven dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: since we are running in jenkins model.. all that is needed is " all needs to be downloaded"  at run time only

Comment: Sorry, I still do not see a problem - you put downloaded jar into your project root directory, add a dependency with path included, and that's it. Jenkins will execute it w/o any problems.
Verified in Jenkins and CircleCI as well.

Comment: we can not check in jar files as it will not allow in bitbucket due to rules set.. and the machine keeps on changing based on the availability.. looks like that we need to download that static files all time manually which is not supposed to be..